# No uidrange rule with IProute2

Tags: networking, ip-routing, raspbian

When I run "ip rule help" there is no uidrange option in the selection sectors. I also get an error when I try to add a uidrange rule.

Iproute2: 4.9.0-1
Command:  sudo ip rule add uidrange $uid-$uid table vpn
Output: Error: argument "uidrange" is wrong: Failed to parse rule type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **uidrange** selector in `ip rule` is available from [version 4.12.0](https://lwn.net/Articles/727186/) of **iproute2**. You have an older version.

Comment: thanks, adding the debian repository to apt fixed it.